# Cambiar el tipo de fuente de letra en python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Que tal he estado trabajando en un proyecto con python y selenium se me presento un problema sobre como cambiar el tipo de fuente de letra en el momento en el que estas recibiendo un texto en una variable. A continuación adjunto mi código:

```
observaciones = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="parrafo"]').text
```

En esta variable recibo un texto con distintos tipos de fuente de letras la idea se me presento cambiar todo el texto a un solo tipo de letra y tamaño, probé con pygame pero me sale un error: "argument of type 'pygame.font.Font' is not iterable"

```
observaciones = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 12)
```

La verdad probé varios ejemplos y busque en varios lugares sin éxito de como poder hacer el cambio de fuente.